# $f'(x)>f(f(x))$ implies $f(f(f(x)))\leq0$ for nonnegative $x$

Tags: calculus

> If $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfies $f'(x)>f(f(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f(f(f(x)))\leq0$ for all $x\geq0$.

Could anybody provide a solution or some hints on this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The context of this problem could help.