# Let $f(x)\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}),\ f^{'}(x)>f(f(x)),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}. $ Prove: $f(f(f(x))))\le 0,\ \forall x\ge0.$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Let $f(x)\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}),\ f^{'}(x)>f(f(x)),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}. $
Prove: $f(f(f(x))))\le 0,\ \forall x\ge0.$
I have just proved $f$ is bonuded. In fact, if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty,\ $ when $x$ is sufficiently big, $$f(x)>1+\epsilon>1,\ f^{'}(x)>f(f(x))>1+\epsilon$$so that when x is more sufficiently big, we have$$f(x)>x,\ f^{'}(x)>f(f(x))>f(x),\ e^{-x}f(x)>c>0,\ f^{'}>ce^{f(x)}$$than$$+\infty>\int_{x_0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{'}(x)}{e^{cf(x)}}=+\infty$$that's a contradiction!
But then I ran out of ideas.

Comment: An Idea, I define: $f^{(n)} = \underbrace{f\circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}}$. We have $f'(f^{(n)}(x) > f^{(n+2)}(x)$. Suppose $f^{(3)}(x) > 0, x \geq 0$, and compute $df^{(3)}/dx$. By applying the assumption, you obtain $f'(f^{(2)}(x))f'(x) > 0$. You can deduce a couple of things from there.

Comment: Someone else asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2573236/1104384) in 2017, however there was no answer there either. Would you mind sharing the source of the question? Just to see if anything pops up anywhere else.

Comment: We might be able to retrieve some of the stuff that is in [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h321705) (from AoPS)? It deals with what happens when we want equality instead of $>$, but maybe some of the ideas could be reused?

Comment: @Pastudent Thank you!

Comment: @BrunoB I just saw it a few days ago. Others told me that it came from IMC. But I read all the tests and couldn't find this problem in AoPS.

Comment: Found it, it's problem 4 of the first day of IMC 2012 (link [here](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2012&item=problems))

Comment: Ok, I may have missed it.